# Differences in strings

Tags: c++

I am stuck on why `*("Harry" + 2 )` and `"Harry"[3]` have the same output (r) but `"Harry" + 1` output is (`arry`). What are the differences?

```
cout << "Harry" + 1 << endl;
cout << *("Harry" + 2 ) << endl;
cout << "Harry"[3] << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Hop on over to https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html for a quick lesson on pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Try it with "Hardy" instead, that might make it clearer for you.

Comment: Because the string contains `a`, then `r`, then `r` ?

Comment: @evan - Perhaps Laurel instead?

Answer (score 3):

`"Harry" + 1` points to one character after `H`, so now the string "lost" a character, `H`.

`*("Harry" + 2)` points to 2 characters after `H`, and so it points to the first `r`. Dereferencing it just the single character, which is `r`.

`"Harry"[3]` gets the third character in `"Harry"`, which is the second `r`. Note that it is syntactic sugar to `*("Harry" + 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

"Harry" is a string of type `const char*`. The `+1` operation gets the address that is one after the beginning address of "Harry", which is the address of the letter `a`. When printed as a string, starting from the second letter, you get "arry". Similarly, "Harry"+2 gets the address of the first `r` letter, so you get `r` when you dereference using `*`. The "Harry"[3] is equivalent to `*("Harry"+3)`, so you should get the second `r` letter, which is still `r`.

In summary, you print a single letter if you dereference using `*`, but you print a string starting from an address of type `const char*` if you don't dereference.

Comment: The type of `"Harry"` is `const char[6]`.

Comment: No, it should be `const char*`. In C/C++, the slowest index of a multi-dimensional array is not fixed-length. It doesn't need to be. You can try `int a="Harry";`, and the compiler will give an error message "invalid conversion from const char* to int", which tells you "Harry" is `const char*` type.

Comment: No, it's an array. Like any array, it can be converted into a pointer to its first element, but it's still an array and not a pointer. You get the error message regarding `const char*` because of that implicit conversion. (And the "slowest" index is always fixed liked the others, but you don't need to specify it because the compiler infers it from the initialiser. You can't declare `int x[][3];`.)

Comment: In fact you can if you do `int x[][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}`. And again, if you do `int y=x;`, the error message that you get is `invalid conversion from int(*)[3] to int`. So only the second index is fixed-length, because that length is needed in the calculation of dereferencing. Since C/C++ do not warn you of subscript out of range, the compiler will not remember the length of the first index. You are allowed to use e.g., x[0][4] to access x[1][1]. Even x[2][4] is sometimes not forbidden unless you have a segmentation fault.

Comment: The first dimension is inferred by the compiler, as I said. In your example, it is 2, and the compiler is fully aware of that. `int (*p)[2][3] = &x;` would be valid, but `int (*p)[3][3] = &x;` wouldn't, and neither would `int (*p)[][3] = &x;`. You're looking at errors *after* the implicit array-pointer decay, which of course mention the decayed type, not the original type.

Comment: I see, so maybe one step of the conversion is already implicitly done, and the error occurs only in the second step of the conversion. Is there a way to show the type of `x` or `p`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123549/discussion-between-zhuoran-he-and-molbdnilo).

Answer (score 0):

Those integers in the first two lines are offset

```
cout << "Harry" + 1 << endl;
```

In this case, we have 1 byte offset: arry so it's gonna print arry

```
cout << *("Harry" + 2 ) << endl;
```

In this case, we have two bytes offset: rry and dereferencing it will print r

```
cout << "Harry"[3] << endl;
```

In this case it's just indexing Harry so it will print r which is the 4th element

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what you created with "Harry".

By definition what you created was a "const char[6]".

That is -- an array of 5 characters, terminated with a null character ('/0').

If you understand this fundamental, then the explanation provided by Rakete should make more sense, again assuming you understand how arrays and pointers work in c++, and the associated syntax of your examples.

Remember! Arrays are zero based.  So when you specify var[3] you are asking for the 4th element.  var[0] would be in this case the first element.

When you are using the stream operators with cout, you are manipulating the starting point of the string, that would typically be var[0].

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, a one-dimensional array can be decayed to a pointer to the first element. So when you write `my_array + 2`, what you are getting is the **address of** the third element in the array. Hence when you write `*(my_array + 2)`, you get the **value**, which is equivalent to writing `my_array[2]`.

Hence the output of `"*(Harry + 2)"` and `"Harry[3]"` is the same (Note: They both are indexing different elements, just that they both are 'r').

When you write `"Harry + 1"`, you are passing the **address of the second element** to cout. cout treats this as a start of string and prints till the end and hence you get the out as `"arry"`

Comment: *can be decayed to